# select query in linq using nhibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

i m using NHibernate 3.3 with linq. When i write a select query it results nothing. 
Code for configuration and oppening session is given bleow.

```
Dim cfg As New Configuration()
                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment. _
                  ConnectionProvider, GetType(NHibernate.Connection. _
                  DriverConnectionProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName)

                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, _
                  GetType(NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect). _
                  AssemblyQualifiedName)

                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, _
                  GetType(NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver). _
                  AssemblyQualifiedName)

                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName, _
  "connectionstring")


                cfg.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment. _
              ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, GetType _
              (NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory). _
              AssemblyQualifiedName)

                Dim s2 As NHibernate.ISessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory

                db = s2.OpenSession()
```

upto here it working fine and query is

```
Dim user As myClass = New myClass
            Dim query = (From my_table In db.Query(Of myClass)() Where user.fname = name Select IMSDK_Users).SingleOrDefault
```

but query return nothing. 
Please help Thanks

Comment: so possibly not users with `fname=name`?

Comment: Might be a problem with your where clause, try without it to confirm.  What is the value of `user.fname` ? and `name` ?

Answer (score 0):

include these namespaces:

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports NHibernate
Imports NHibernate.Linq
```

and try this:

```
Dim query = (From c In db.Query(Of myClass)() Where c.fname = name Select c).FirstOrDefault()
```